# How do I return multiple values in a function return in lua

Tags: lua

I am trying to return GetUserGroup into multiple values but it only returns into 1 i tried using the for statement but did not work and I don't want to do `ply:GetUserGroup() == "owner"` or `ply:GetUserGroup() == "superadmin"` that is the only way of fixing the problem but its going to be a long line and I cant have that

This is the darkrp addentity code:

```
DarkRP.createEntity("Money printer", {
    ent = "money_printer",
    model = "models/props_c17/consolebox01a.mdl",
    price = 1000,
    cmd = "buymoneyprinter",
    getMax = function(ply) 
    local limitRanks = {"odyssian", "tmod", "dmod", "dadmin", "admin", "superadmin", "co-owner", "owner"}
    return ply:GetUserGroup() == limitRanks and 6 or 3 
    end,
})
```

Comment: I'm confused. You want to test the returned value from `ply:GetUserGroup()` against multiple values? Or you want to return multiple values from the `GetUserGroup` itself?

Comment: I want to return limitranks table into the ply:GetUserGroup() so that i dont have to copy and paste it over and over

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*return limitranks table into the ply:GetUserGroup()*". Do you mean passing `limitranks` as a parameter into it? Like eg. `ply:GetUserGroup(limitranks)`?

Comment: Clarify your question with a simple example, given some input `ply`  what should calling `getMax(ply)` return as output? Are there any side-effects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to turn `limitRanks` into a hash table and check if the key is present in the return statement:

```
local limitRanks = {odyssian = true, tmod = true, dmod = true, dadmin = true,
  admin = true, superadmin = true, ["co-owner"] = true, owner = true}
return limitRanks[ply:GetUserGroup()] and 6 or 3
```

Comment: @XQuantumForceX Where did you put this `local` line? You should have replaced your `local limitRanks` line with this one.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thats what i did i replaced the old one with this new one and got that error

Comment: @XQuantumForceX, I replaced lines 7-8 in your code with my three lines and don't get any errors. Make sure you keep `getMax = function(ply)` line; if I remove it, I get the same error you got.

Comment: @PaulKulchenko Sorry about that i miss spelled something and it made that error it was late at night but thank you it worked.

Comment: @XQuantumForceX, you may want to accept the answer if it works for you.